# How to change the url in smartAdmin AngularJs 1.8 version?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, smartadmin

I am trying to change the path in the state routing in build/app.js but it loads the layout.tpl.html always with /dashboard url not loading the template with any other url. Please can anybody tell me how to change it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily to to the app.config.js file and change the root of the URL